# Requires Full Screen is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7, build-settings

In Xcode project, it enters full screen view only after entering the below code and not by simply enable Requires full screen.Why? And, am i missing anything?

```
    public override bool PrefersStatusBarHidden()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What are we defining full-screen view as for this purpose? You actually mean just visibility or absence of the status bar, or are you referring to multitasking?

Answer (score 0):

`UIRequiresFullScreen` is used to disable multitasking mode in iPad

Comment: this worked to enter app full screen before, but not now.